# Implementing SSO on restful service

Tags: c#, rest, single-sign-on, owin, claims-based-identity

We have a whole bunch of clients that want us to start using their ADFS to allow their users into our web app using Single-Sign-On.

After reading up on WIF (which seemed to be the solution at first but is deprecated in VS 2013...), OWIN, oAuth, OpenID Connect, I'm completely confused as to the simplest way to implement SSO.

What is the best and simplest technology to use to implement SSO on an existing **VS 2013** json restful service written in C#?

Ideally the technology would already be part of .NET.

Are there any code samples or tutorials out there for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that you want to consume your service from native clients, I would recommend that you protect your service using Web API middleware (which was already supported via OWIN middleware in VS2013) and implement your clients using the ADAL library. For a post specifically on ADAL and ADFS, see [this](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/25/securing-a-web-api-with-adfs-on-ws2012-r2-got-even-easier/). For more details on the Web API side of the solution, see [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-client). If you want to target a variety of client platforms, you can find a complete collection of samples (for Azure AD, but easy to modify for ADFS) [here](https://github.com/Azure-samples?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=native).

Comment: thanks. I still need to do proof of concepts but you seem to have pointed me in the right direction. This link seems to be the most useful: http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/25/securing-a-web-api-with-adfs-on-ws2012-r2-got-even-easier/

Answer (score 1):

This can be implemented through WSO2 IS as Relying Party in ADFS. When we will implement this setup the outcome/Income claims will be main source for User Profile load to WSO2IS for authentication and pass the SAML Response to SP(End URL of your application).

Refer the below links to configure WSO2 IS as relying party for ADFS and WSO2 IS configuration too.

https://omindu.wordpress.com/2015/06/19/setting-ad-fs-3-0-as-federated-authenticator-in-wso2-identity-server/

Comment: wow...thanks but WSO2 looks like a complete parallel universe! Does not seem like the simplest solution to me... unless you can find a simple C# code sample on how to use it...

Answer (score 0):

SSO would mean its Active Directory driven, or direct to IIS machine.config authentication instead of a web.config, but also considering the "simplest technology" you've mentioned, then this must be a call for something simple yet you can transform into what you really desire.

With this, we can refer to token-based web services authentication.
Here's a sample project from which I started and able to transform into something else. From here I think you can then change all authentications into AD or DB connect, or even both across your web services.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9348/Web-Service-Authentication?fid=145460&df=90&mpp=25&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Normal&spc=Relaxed&fr=26#xx0xx

hopefully this would help.

Comment: Sry, this is not an SSO project...I already have tons of projects doing authentication. I need a c# project that is NOT ASP.net but a json service and that uses some library to perform SSO against ADFS.

Comment: Actually..the ASP.NET thing is just a sample..I actually converted the page sample into .asmx web service for authenticated sending and receiving JSON or XML whatever the requirement is..